# Rails: Having trouble running Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get my `rails console` to work properly. This is a new macbook pro that I migrated, if that matters.

I ran `bundle` and `bundle update` already...

Versions: 
Rails 5.2.1
Ruby 2.3.3

The error I'm getting:

```
$ rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 9953
/Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require': dlopen(/Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.7.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin17/readline.bundle
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<main>'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:4:in `<main>'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `each'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:80:in `block in lookup'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `each'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:79:in `lookup'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in `find_by_namespace'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-5.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/code/recipes/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/bootsnap-1.3.2/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `block in load'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:253:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:281:in `load'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/joshuacesana/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

This is just more nonsense because StackOverFlow says I need more details.... enjoy some Back to the Future quotes:

Alright, we're the pinheads. Uh, no, no, no, no. What are you looking at, butt-head? Your, your right. Wow, ah Red, you look great. Everything looks great. 1:24, I still got time. Oh my god. No, no not again, c'mon, c'mon. Hey. Libyans. Give me a hand, Lorenzo. Ow, dammit, man, I sliced my hand.

That's George McFly. Flux capacitor. That's right. Oh, oh Marty, here's you keys. You're all waxed up, ready for tonight. Back to the future.

Its good. Mom, is that you? No, get out of town, my mom thinks I'm going camping with the guys. Well, Jennifer, my mother would freak out if she knew I was going up there with you. And I get this standard lecture about how she never did that kind of stuff when she was a kid. Now look, I think she was born a nun. What? Say, why do you let those boys push you around like that?

Comment: The stacktrace shows a libreadline load error, do you have the libreadline package installed?

Comment: Do you have `gem 'rb-readline'` in your Gemfile ?

Comment: Bingo! Problem solved. Thank you @arieljuod

Comment: and thank you @KedarnagMukanahallipatna

Comment: @sawa I was trying to get rails console to work. Sorry I guess I did not explicitly ask that. Anyhoo, I was already helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error logs, looks like you are missing `libreadline` installed on your machine. Could you try this [link](https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Add-Readline-support-to-Ruby-on-Mac-OS-X) to install `readline` on your Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `brew install readline`